# Edit value on woocommerce checkout billing fields

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

So, I want to put a custom value on the **first name** and **last name** fields on the checkout page.
I can use this hook in order to change all field properties beside the value:

```html
// WooCommerce Checkout Fields Hook
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_wc_checkout_fields' );
// Change order comments placeholder and label, and set billing phone number to not required.
function custom_wc_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    $fields['billing']['billing_last_name']['required'] = true;
    $fields['billing']['billing_last_name']['placeholder'] = 'whatever';
    $fields['billing']['billing_last_name']['value'] = 'not working';
    $fields['billing']['billing_first_name']['required'] = true;
    $fields['billing']['billing_first_name']['placeholder'] = 'whatever';
    $fields['billing']['billing_first_name']['value'] = 'not working';
    return $fields;
}
```

in their [codex](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/) they don't mention any option for doing that.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

$fields['billing']['billing_first_name']['default'] = 'working';